# Selenium IDE throwing an error when selecting an option from dropdown menu

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm using selenium IDE, and I received an error when trying to select an option in a drop down menu. The error message:

> Element name = aggravation [] 556 [shares] not found.

This the command in question

`|select| |name=aggravation[]556[shares] |label=2|`

and this is the source code

```
<select name="aggravation[]556[shares]" id="aggravation_556_shares" class="shares" data-id="556" style=""><option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Why am I getting this error? Is my code wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [] are giving issues, the error also shows spaces between them, which I think is weird.

**Better selector:**

I would try to use the id or css instead:

```
id=aggravation_556_shares
```

or

```
css=select.shares
```

Read more about selectors here: http://www.guru99.com/locators-in-selenium-ide.html

**Visible:**

Are you certain the element is visible when you try to find it? Maybe the page is just a bit (milliseconds) slower than your test. You might need to wait until the element is visible. Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341758/how-to-wait-until-element-present

Comment: I tried what you wrote down but still it does not work for me, about the time I need to wait how do I know what to put in terms of the wait

Comment: Can't you use the recorder of the IDE and see what kind of code it generates? I haven't used Selenium IDE in years, don't really know, just wanted to suggest you some directions. Read the documentation? :)

Comment: Yes I use the recording, and read the document.
I also did something similar in C # that can help that where I get the same error .                                                                                        newSelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("aggrupations_556_shares"))).SelectByText("3");